# Work with XPath to select the item with the highest z-index value

Tags: html, xpath

Need to work with the selector with the highest z-index value

```
<div style="position: fixed;width: 400px;height: 278px;overflow: hidden;box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 6px;bottom: 0px;transition: transform 2s ease 0s;right: 120px;z-index: 2;" class="Cl"><iframe id="t1dxvk58p7cu" name="t1dxvk58p7cu" class="Xyqxtc" allow="camera" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: transparent; overflow: hidden; border: none;"></iframe></div>
<div style="position: fixed;width: 400px;height: 278px;overflow: hidden;box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 6px;bottom: 0px;transition: transform 2s ease 0s;right: 120px;z-index: 3;" class="Cl"><iframe id="t1dxvk58p7cu" name="t1dxvk58p7cu" class="Xyqxtc" allow="camera" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: transparent; overflow: hidden; border: none;"></iframe></div>
<div style="position: fixed;width: 400px;height: 278px;overflow: hidden;box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 6px;bottom: 0px;transition: transform 2s ease 0s;right: 120px;z-index: 4;" class="Cl"><iframe id="t1dxvk58p7cu" name="t1dxvk58p7cu" class="Xyqxtc" allow="camera" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: transparent; overflow: hidden; border: none;"></iframe></div>
```

I tried below but failed

```
//div[@class='Cl'][substring-after(@style,'z-index:') > substring-after(../div[@class='Cl']/@style,'z-index:')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XPath 2.0 solution using regex `replace` and `max`

```
//div[@class='Cl' and replace(@style,'^.*?z-index: (\d+).*?$','$1') = max(../div[@class='Cl']/replace(@style,'^.*?z-index: (\d+).*?$','$1'))]
```

the main idea is

- extract the z-index from the style-attribute using replace
- and compare it to the maximum z-index of similar elements: `div[id = max(../div/id)]`
  (id equals the extracted z-index)

[Live Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3A%20fixed%3Bwidth%3A%20400px%3Bheight%3A%20278px%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3Bbox-shadow%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.2)%200px%202px%206px%3Bbottom%3A%200px%3Btransition%3A%20transform%202s%20ease%200s%3Bright%3A%20120px%3Bz-index%3A%202%3B%22%20class%3D%22Cl%22%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20name%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20class%3D%22Xyqxtc%22%20allow%3D%22camera%22%20style%3D%22height%3A%20100%25%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20background%3A%20transparent%3B%20overflow%3A%20hidden%3B%20border%3A%20none%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3A%20fixed%3Bwidth%3A%20400px%3Bheight%3A%20278px%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3Bbox-shadow%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.2)%200px%202px%206px%3Bbottom%3A%200px%3Btransition%3A%20transform%202s%20ease%200s%3Bright%3A%20120px%3Bz-index%3A%203%3B%22%20class%3D%22Cl%22%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20name%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20class%3D%22Xyqxtc%22%20allow%3D%22camera%22%20style%3D%22height%3A%20100%25%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20background%3A%20transparent%3B%20overflow%3A%20hidden%3B%20border%3A%20none%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3A%20fixed%3Bwidth%3A%20400px%3Bheight%3A%20278px%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3Bbox-shadow%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.2)%200px%202px%206px%3Bbottom%3A%200px%3Btransition%3A%20transform%202s%20ease%200s%3Bright%3A%20120px%3Bz-index%3A%204%3B%22%20class%3D%22Cl%22%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20name%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20class%3D%22Xyqxtc%22%20allow%3D%22camera%22%20style%3D%22height%3A%20100%25%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20background%3A%20transparent%3B%20overflow%3A%20hidden%3B%20border%3A%20none%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22position%3A%20fixed%3Bwidth%3A%20400px%3Bheight%3A%20278px%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3Bbox-shadow%3A%20rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.2)%200px%202px%206px%3Bbottom%3A%200px%3Btransition%3A%20transform%202s%20ease%200s%3Bright%3A%20120px%3Bz-index%3A%205%3B%22%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20name%3D%22t1dxvk58p7cu%22%20class%3D%22Xyqxtc%22%20allow%3D%22camera%22%20style%3D%22height%3A%20100%25%3B%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%20background%3A%20transparent%3B%20overflow%3A%20hidden%3B%20border%3A%20none%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27Cl%27%20and%20replace(%40style%2C%27%5E.*%3Fz-index%3A%20(%5Cd%2B).*%3F%24%27%2C%27%241%27)%20%3D%20max(..%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27Cl%27%5D%2Freplace(%40style%2C%27%5E.*%3Fz-index%3A%20(%5Cd%2B).*%3F%24%27%2C%27%241%27))%5D%0A%0A&=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27Cl%27%20and%20replace(%40style%2C%27%5E.*%3Fz-index%3A%20(%5Cd%2B).*%3F%24%27%2C%27%241%27)%20%3D%20max(..%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27Cl%27%5D%2Freplace(%40style%2C%27%5E.*%3Fz-index%3A%20(%5Cd%2B).*%3F%24%27%2C%27%241%27))%5D&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath3)

and here is another one that follows the schema `div/[not(..div/id > id)]`:

```
//div[@class='Cl' and not(../div[@class='Cl']/replace(@style,'^.*?z-index: (\d+).*?$','$1') > replace(@style,'^.*?z-index: (\d+).*?$','$1'))]
```

References:

- [XPath to get the element with the highest ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786443/xpath-to-get-the-element-with-the-highest-id) (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512987/8291949))
- [Regex - Extract a substring from a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507388/regex-extract-a-substring-from-a-given-string) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787008/8291949) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786761/8291949) answer)

Comment: @GamiDPC Sorry, Chrome uses XPath 1.0. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25455588/8291949 See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=689271

Comment: And you can redo it to work in chrome, but I did not understand what to do.

Comment: @GamiDPC no, since XPath 1.0 does not support regular expressions and I do not see a way to rewrite this without extraction the z-index. Your best bet is to use a programming language like (like JS, Python, etc.) to handle the extraction on comparison of all selected divs.